# jQuery Mobile Collapsibles with Databases

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a web page with collapsible content using jQuery Mobile Collapsibles. I'm referring [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_collapsibles.asp). I want to display $row['Host'] as title and $row['IP'] as content. My script doesn't display anything? Where I'm wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "pass");
if (!$con) {
    die("Error: " . mysql_error());
}


mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytbl");
?>

<?php 
// display the results returned
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
   <h3><?=$row['Host']?></h3>
   <p><?=$row['IP']?><p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your HTML.

Basically you are exporting DB data after HTML tag closure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

YOUR PHP CODE IS HERE
```

Change it to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "pass");
        if (!$con) {
            die("Error: " . mysql_error());
        }


        mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytbl");
        ?>

        <?php 
        // display the results returned
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
           <h3><?=$row['Host']?></h3>
           <p><?=$row['IP']?><p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a web programmer..Sorry about that mistake, but still I don't get results?It is just empty?Do you see any thing wrong in my script?

Comment: Does your file has php extension? Your code is working just fine if filename has php extension, it will fail if your file has html extension and your php web server is not configured to load html files

Comment: Got it..Problem was with the extension. Thanks very much for pointing it out.